# ASP Net Radio Button List Checked & Custom Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a asp radio button list which has 3 options:

Option 1
Option 2
Option 3

Think of this as a question as such and "Option 2" is the correct option to select which will take you to a success page.

What is the code to be able to do this?

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

If a user chooses "Option 1" I need to be able to show a custom validation message saying something like "Nearly but not quite - please try again"

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Option 1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Option 2"></asp:ListItem>
```

in your `SelectedIndexChanged`

```
if (YourRedioButtionID.SelectedValue.ToString() == "0")
            {
               Responce.Redirest("successpage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                //your message in level.
            }
```

Comment: Perfect Shree Khanal! Thanks heaps for all your help :-D